# Why include jQuery and underscore in every JS file in Backbone/Require.js project

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

In almost every Backbone/Require.js project you will see models and views that look similar to this:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
], function ($, _, Backbone) {
    //Some code goes here, perhaps a Backbone model or view
});
```

But, assuming that you set up your Require.js shims correctly (with the Backbone shim including something like `deps: ["underscore", "jquery"]`) you only need to define Backbone--defining Backbone as a dependency implicitly defines jQuery and Underscore as dependencies as well!  Thus this would also be correct:

```
define([
    'backbone'
], function (Backbone) {
    //Some code goes here, perhaps a Backbone model or view
});
```

Personally, I would define jQuery or Underscore in a file that explicitly used their functions--but in something like a simple no-frills Backbone model file, they seem like cruft.

Why do I so frequently see the pattern of superfluous jQuery and Underscore definitions?  Why has this become an unquestioned best practice?

Comment: what if you want to use a module you've defined in another project?

Comment: You answered your question : *Personally, I would define jQuery or Underscore in a file that explicitly used their functions--but in something like a simple no-frills Backbone model file, they **are**  cruft.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declaring Underscore and jQuery as dependencies when you don't explicitly need them as variables in your module doesn't serve any purpose (i.e. it is not a best practice). As you said in your question

> Personally, I would define jQuery or Underscore in a file that
>   explicitly used their functions--but in something like a simple
>   no-frills Backbone model file, they seem like cruft.

Moreover, you can even get rid of them in some situations:

- in views, use [`this.$`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar) to access the local DOM, [`this.$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-%24el) for the element
- [`Backbone.$`](http://backbonejs.org/#Utility-Backbone-%24) stores a reference to jQuery
- use the proxied methods of Underscore on [models](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-Underscore-Methods) and [collections](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods)

Answer (score 1):

It's done only because of avoiding using global variables. Of course you can skip defining jQuery and underscore but `$` and `_` will refer to the global variables in this case. In case you create your own application and use single version of jQuery - it will not case issues, but if your application already includes few different library versions - it's better to follow practice you do not like to follow :)